# Peculiar "assets" link type on GitHub's homepage 

Tags: html

I found the following snippet in the source code of GitHub's homepage:

```html
<head>
...
<link rel="assets" href="https://github.githubassets.com/">
...
</head>
```

Since I wasn't familiar with the `assets` [link type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) I tried to look it up 
but couldn't find any documentation so I checked the markup validity with the [W3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/) which returned *"Bad value assets for attribute rel on element link: The string assets is not a registered keyword"*.

Is the `assets` link type is some sort of typo, hack or even an undocumented feature?

Comment: I have `<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://github.githubassets.com">` when I go on the github homepage

Comment: My bad. You're right, ```ref```attribute isn't part of any standard. I actually mispelled it. It actually says ```rel```which is a very common attribute used with the ```link``` tag.

Comment: @Seblor Yes, that's in the source code as well. The snippet I'm referring to is a couple of lines below.

Comment: Ah you are right. This is weird indeed.

Comment: Quite peculiar. I don't think it's a bug, otherwise I'd report it to them.

Comment: I noticed it too. As far as I know, it is non-standard. My guess is that they use it for some internal process, and are perhaps hoping it will at some point be standardized because they’re pretty big. (Remember, even something as silly as `apple-touch-icon` was standardized as some point.)